# How to post value of input type to another php page through jquery ?

Tags: javascript, php

Please help me, I don't know what's the exactly question about this.
I have form of the chat (chat.php)

```
<div class="panel-collapse">
    <div class="panel-body"><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
        <ul class="chat" id="chat">
        </ul>
    </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                    Send
                </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-footer -->
</div>

<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/chat.js"></script>
```

And here's my script (chat.js)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
done();

});

function done() {
     setTimeout( function() { 
     updates();
     done();
     }, 200);

}

function updates() {
$.getJSON("check_chat.php", function(data) {
    $("#chat").empty();
    $.each(data.result, function(){
    $("#chat").append("<li class='left clearfix'><span class='chat-img pull-left'><img src='logo.png' alt='User Avatar' class='img-circle' /></span><div class='chat-body clearfix'><div class='header'><strong class='primary-font'>"+this['_id']+"</strong><small class='pull-right text-muted'><i class='fa fa-clock-o fa-fw'></i> 12 mins ago</small></div><p align='justify'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p></div></li>");

    });
});
}
```

And this is the searching machine (check_chat.php)

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('basarnas');
$query = $db->informasi_bencana;
$cursor=$query->find(array("_id"=>new MongoId($_GET['id'])));
$result = array();
foreach($cursor as $id=>$doc){
array_push($result, array('_id'=>$doc['_id'],
                    'nama_pelapor'=>decrypt($doc['nama_pelapor'], $key),
                    'no_telp'=>decrypt($doc['no_telp'], $key)));    
    }
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

My input type hidden could get $_GET['id'], but in this searching machine (check_data.php) couldn't get $_GET['id']. How can I get the id ($_GET['id']) ? I think there's something way to post from my input type hidden to check_data.php but I don't know what's the question when I was searching in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, you should consider using `setInterval` isntead of `setTimeout` in your done() function
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

check_chat.php wont be able to read the $_GET['id'] as he's being processed as a different file, where $_GET['id'] is not declared. To fix that, you have to send `id` to the file using the .getJSON request. You could do that with:

```
function updates() {
    $.getJSON("check_chat.php", { id:  $("#id").val() }, function (data) {
        $("#chat").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("#chat").append("<li class='left clearfix'><span class='chat-img pull-left'><img src='logo.png' alt='User Avatar' class='img-circle' /></span><div class='chat-body clearfix'><div class='header'><strong class='primary-font'>" + this['_id'] + "</strong><small class='pull-right text-muted'><i class='fa fa-clock-o fa-fw'></i> 12 mins ago</small></div><p align='justify'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur bibendum ornare dolor, quis ullamcorper ligula sodales.</p></div></li>");

        });
    });
}
```

You see `{ id:  $("#id").val() }`, we're sending the id as well to the file check_chat.php

Comment: How can I get id in check_chat.php ? Sorry I'm Newbie.